# Screen touch repeater

Tags: touchscreen

I am looking for a device that could repeat touches at a certain location of a capacitor touchscreen repeatedly, preferably with at least a few time intervals a user can choose from for the repeats.

Anything from robotic index fingers to self-adhesive touch repeater can go, preferably sub-$100; however, no software solution is viable, the OS is closed and proprietary.

Comment: actual touches or a usb thing you plug in that pretends to be a touchscreen but isn't?

Comment: On-point question, thank you! This is to be used on the touchscreen of a car, and its Linux-based OS no longer allows such software manipulation sadly. So it’s gotta be something that actually effects  a touch be detected on the screen.